# How to append one DataTable to another DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable

I would like to append one DataTable to another DataTable. I see the DataTable class has two methods; "Load(IDataReader)" and "Merge(DataTable)".  From the documentation, both appear to 'merge' the incoming data with the existing DataTable if rows exist. I will be doing the merge in a data access layer.

I could use an `IDataReader` and use the Load method to merge the DataTables. Or I could load a DataSet using the `IDataReader`, get the DataTable from the DataSet, and then use the Merge method to merge the DataTables.

I was wondering if someone could tell me which is the proper method to use?

Alternatively, let me know if you have a different suggestion on how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Merge takes a DataTable, Load requires an IDataReader - so depending on what your data layer gives you access to, use the required method. My understanding is that Load will internally call Merge, but not 100% sure about that.

If you have two DataTables, use Merge.

Answer (score 84):

The datatype in the same columns name must be equals.

```
dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2);
```

After that the result is:

dataTable1 = dataTable1 + dataTable2

Answer (score 21):

You could let your `DataAdapter` do the work.  `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` will append your new rows to any existing rows in `DataTable`.

Comment: Makes hard task look easy !

Answer (score 6):

Add two datasets containing datatables, now it will merge as required

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(System.String)));

DataRow newSelRow1 = dt1.NewRow();
newSelRow1["Column1"] = "Select";
dt1.Rows.Add(newSelRow1);

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(System.String)));

DataRow newSelRow2 = dt1.NewRow();
newSelRow2["Column1"] = "DataRow1Data";  // Data
dt2.Rows.Add(newSelRow2);

ds1.Tables.Add(dt1);
ds2.Tables.Add(dt2);

ds1.Tables[0].Merge(ds2.Tables[0]);
```

Now ds1 will have the merged data

Comment: No need to go hard when there are easy and built-in ways to do the exact same job. Already caught up with tremendous pressure as a programmer :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider a solution that will neatly handle arbitrarily many tables.

```
//ASSUMPTION: All tables must have the same columns
var tables = new List<DataTable>();
tables.Add(oneTableToRuleThemAll);
tables.Add(oneTableToFindThem);
tables.Add(oneTableToBringThemAll);
tables.Add(andInTheDarknessBindThem);
//Or in the real world, you might be getting a collection of tables from some abstracted data source.

//behold, a table too great and terrible to imagine
var theOneTable = tables.SelectMany(dt => dt.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Encapsulated into a helper for future reuse:

```
public static DataTable CombineDataTables(params DataTable[] args)
{
    return args.SelectMany(dt => dt.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Just have a few tables declared in code?

```
var combined = CombineDataTables(dt1,dt2,dt3);
```

Want to combine into one of the existing tables instead of creating a new one?

```
dt1 = CombineDataTables(dt1,dt2,dt3);
```

Already have a collection of tables, instead of declared one by one?

```
//Pretend variable tables already exists
var tables = new[] { dt1, dt2, dt3 };
var combined = CombineDataTables(tables);
```

Comment: datatable.merge doesnt preserve row order. so this is better when you need to keep row order.

Answer (score -1):

use loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {      
           dt2.Rows.Add(dt1.Rows[i][0], dt1.Rows[i][1], ...);//you have to insert all Columns...
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure this fullfil the request of the main question. Please check it.