# How to call one stored procedure several times and fill one data table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one stored procedure that call several times and result fill one data table. can i first call stored procedure several times and at the end fill data table or any time calls stored procedure, fills data table same time? can i use loop for call stored procedure and at the end fill data table.
 is it possible?  How do?

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "SP_LastRead", conn);
            DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            for (int i = 0; i < query3.Count(); i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoWater", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = query3.Select(m=>m.SharingNo).ToString();
            }
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dtData.Load(rdr);
```

I want to call 'SP_LastRead' several times and at the end fill 'dtData'.

Comment: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Question is not clear. Take your time and post the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Just store query result in another data table and append it to the dtData in question using logic described in this question [How to append one DataTable to another DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858401/how-to-append-one-datatable-to-another-datatable)