# Populate DataTable from other smaller DataTables

Tags: c#, asynchronous, datatable

I have an `async` operation will goes out and populates a DataTable with some parameters and it's repeated a couple of times, so each time it goes out it will get a DataTable.

I want to save each of these smaller DataTables into a larger DataTable. I'm trying this where `DataTable table` is the table which represents the smaller Datatable and `dtMain` is the larger DataTable. I have this in a loop and each iteration, the `table` should copy over its `Rows` into `dtMain`:

```
    DataTable table = await SomeOperationWhichReturnsADataTable();
    DataTable dtMain;

    if (dtMain.Rows.Count == 0) // Copy over Rows and Columns since dtMain is empty
    {
        dtMain = table.Copy();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows) // Just copy the Rows
        {
            dtMain.Rows.Add(dataRow.ItemArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this other than just Copying the Rows over for each table?

Comment: What's dsActv? Is it a dataset?

Comment: Consider using `DataTable.Merge` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append one DataTable to another DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858401/how-to-append-one-datatable-to-another-datatable)

Comment: @sr28 Sorry was supposed to be `dtMain`

Comment: if you have a choice then you should always let Sql to do the dirty work instead of doing this in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the DataTable [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx) method? i believe you can change your code to something like this:

```
DataTable table = await SomeOperationWhichReturnsADataTable();
DataTable dtMain;
/*Not sure about this validation as no information about dsActv
 was provided so i will leave it as is*/
if (dsActv.Rows.Count == 0) // Copy over Rows and Columns
{
    dtMain= table.Copy();
}
else
{
    dtMain.Merge(table);
}
```